# .py a .exe Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, exe

Estoy tratando de hacer un .exe con un archivo .py. Me leí el tutorial de http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial y me funciono a la perfección. Mi problema es cuando en vez de hacer un código tan fácil como el del tutorial `print "Hello world"` coloco funciones como por ejemplo:

```
def main():
    a = 14
    print a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Instalarlo y crear el .exe lo hace pero cuando quiero ejecutarlo solo me abre y cierra rápido la ventana de la terminal.

proble agregando raw_input() y en el codigo escrito previamente corre bien. Ahora dejo mi codigo real que necesito correr para ver si me puede encontrar una solucion:

```
# coding=utf-8
from urllib import urlencode
import pycurl
import pprint
import json
from io import BytesIO
import ast
import requests
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import date, timedelta
import zipfile


def main():
    url_login('https://partners.streamrail.com/api/v2/login')
    login('marti', '44444')
    report('https://partners.streamrail.com/data-export/data/custom/5a2ff9a88783470002ad62bd', 'Top20_Media_Yesterday.zip')
    zip('Top20_Media_Yesterday.zip')
    Top20("Top20_Media_Yesterday.zip","Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")
    Orden_imp()
    name_csv_top20('Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv')
    remove_files("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv","Top20_Media_Yesterday.zip")


def url_login(url): #Llamado a la url del login
    global data
    data = BytesIO()
    global c
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)


def login(user,passwd): #Usuario y contraseña, almacenamiento de token tambien
    post_data = {'username': user, 'password': passwd}
    postfields = urlencode(post_data)
    c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
    c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, data.write) #Eliminar esta y las del dicc para volver al codigo original
    c.perform()
    dictionary = json.loads(data.getvalue())
    global d
    d = dictionary["access_token"]


def report(url_report, name_file): #Url del reporte + almacenamiento del reporte en zip
    url = url_report 
    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(d)
        }
    data = name_file #Nombre del reporte
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers) #almacena reporte en la variable
    with open(data, 'wb') as f: #Save report
            for chunk in response.iter_content():
                f.write(chunk)
    print response.status_code,("(status_code)"),("- Reporte descargado:"), response.status_code == requests.codes.ok


def zip(name_zip): #Extraccion del zip
    zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(name_zip, 'r')
    zip_ref.extractall()
    zip_ref.close()

def Top20(name_zip, output_file): #Modificacion CSV zip a csv con el top 20 de la media
    #Creacion y lectura de CSV's
    with zipfile.ZipFile(name_zip) as z:
        lista = z.namelist()
        global filename
        filename = ''.join(lista)
    with open(filename) as csvfile, open(output_file,  "w") as output:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        cols = ("domain","ddomain","opportunities", "impressions", "fillRate", "DATA")
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=cols, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()
        #Operaciones para llegar al top 20 Media
        for row in reader:
            row['fillRate'] = '{:.2f}'.format(float(row['fillRate']) * 100)
            if row['ddomain']  == "":
                if row['domain']  == "":
                    row['ddomain'] = "App"
                    row['domain'] = " "
            if row['domain'] == row['ddomain']:
                row['domain'] = "Real Site"    
            if row['domain']  == "":
                row['domain'] = "Detected Only"
            if row['ddomain']  == "":
                row['ddomain'] = "Vast Media"
            if row['ddomain'] != row['domain']:
                if row['ddomain'] != "Vast Media":
                    if row['domain'] != "Real Site":
                        if row['domain'] != "Detected Only":
                            if row['ddomain'] != "App":
                                row['DATA'] = "FAKE"
                            else:
                                row['DATA'] = "OK"
                        else:
                            row['DATA'] = "OK"
                    else:
                        row['DATA'] = "OK"
                else:
                    row['DATA'] = "OK"
            writer.writerow(row)


def Orden_imp():
#Orden y de mayor a menor en impresiones
    movies = pd.read_csv('Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv')
    movies = movies.sort_values(['impressions'], ascending=False) #Orden de mayor a menor impresiones
    movies = movies.to_csv("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")
    movies = pd.read_csv('Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv', nrows=20) #Top 20 media yesteday
    movies = movies.to_csv("Top20_Media_Yesterday.csv")


def name_csv_top20(name): #Nombre file fecha yesterday + creacion CSV

    yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
    fecha = yesterday.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
    base ='Top20_Media_{}.csv'.format(fecha)
    with open(name, 'r') as csvfile, open(base,  "w") as output:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        cols = ("domain","ddomain","opportunities", "impressions", "fillRate", "DATA")
        writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=cols, extrasaction='ignore')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)

    #Cambio de nombre celda (domain to Category)
    r = csv.reader(open(base)) 
    lines = [l for l in r]
    lines[0][0] = 'Category'
    writer = csv.writer(open(base, 'w'))
    writer.writerows(lines)


def remove_files(topcsv,zipf):
    #Borrado de archivos innecesarios
    os.remove(topcsv)
    os.remove(filename)
    os.remove(zipf)

    print("YOUR TOP 20 MEDIA IS DONE")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

raw_input()
```

Ademas agrego el codigo de mi setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe



setup(console=['Media_Yesterday_Top20.py'],
      options={
                'py2exe': { 
                'dll_excludes': ["ADVAPI32.dll",
                                 "WLDAP32.dll"]

              }

                })
```

Answer (score 1):

En windows puedes hacer uso del modulo mcvcrt. Al inicio de tu programa lo importas:
import msvcrt
Y despues al final de tu programa pones:
msvcrt.getch()
Con esto es suficiente para que el programa se quede esperando una pulsacion de teclado para salir.

Tambien existe otra variante usando la funcion para leer desde teclado.
Como ultima linea de tu programa pones:
raw_input()

Y el cmd permanecera abierto hasta que lo cierres o pulses una tecla, este ultimo metodo es valido para cualquier sistema operativo mientras que el primer metodo solo es valido en windows.

Comment: Sirvio con un codigo simple pero no con el mio, ahi edite mi pregunta. @Jean Gotopo

Comment: Te corrió bien e archivo .py? Porque a mi me sale error de sintaxis en la linea 58.

Comment: edite la pregunta nuevamente para que veas el codigo de mi setup.py

Comment: edite pregunta, la ves?

Comment: Si la veo, tan solo que me sigue dando error de sintaxis. Estoy tratando de ver cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 1):

pyinstaller es mejor opcion para compilar un .exe de windows.

http://www.pyinstaller.org/

pip install pyinstaller

pyinstaller yourprogram.py

Answer (score 0):

Es pyinstaller de manera amigable

Utiliza auto-py-to exe

intenta con el cmd para ver la parte del codigo con error